# Отловить нажатие левой кнопки мыши

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый всем день! Пытаюсь отловить нажатие левой кнопки мыши, но ничего не происходит!

```
private void s_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
        isSelect = false;
}
```

Стал проверять, почему-то это условие срабатывает только когда нажимается правая кнопка мыши! Подскажите пожалуйста почему так происходит? Почему когда события устанавливаю на левую кнопку мыши они не срабатывают?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте событие `PreviewMouseUp`, для того чтобы добиться требуемого результата

```
private void s_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            isSelect = false;
}
```

в XAML

```
<Button PreviewMouseUp="s_PreviewMouseUp" ... />
```